# modular arithmetic-mod of huge numbers in c++

Tags: c++, modular-arithmetic

In my short sports programming career i encountered many time Calculating mod of numbers like

```
26164615615665561165154564545......%(10000007)
```

I have done some research but could only find calculation of mods of numbers in the form

```
(a^b)%c
```

can anybody explain how to calculate mod of numbers like the first example.

Comment: this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Example_implementations ? How are your numbers even stored anyway ?

Comment: @Lectem I have read that...the whole article..

Answer (score 2):

C++ does not have any long integer arithmetic facilities as part of the standard library.
If you want to compute with long integers, you need to rely on an external library.

Two good choices seem to be

- GMP: https://gmplib.org - if you are not afraid of C-like interface (there is also gmpxx though)
- NTL: http://www.shoup.net/ntl/ - my personal favourite, provides clear and easy interface (e.g. class ZZ for long integers and ZZ_p for long integers modulo)

Here is an example (taken from [NTL examples](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/tour-ex1.html)) of how a modular exponentiation could be done using NTL:

```
ZZ PowerMod(const ZZ& a, const ZZ& e, const ZZ& n)
{
   if (e == 0) return ZZ(1);

   long k = NumBits(e);
   ZZ res;
   res = 1;

   for (long i = k-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      res = (res*res) % n;
      if (bit(e, i) == 1) res = (res*a) % n;
   }
   if (e < 0)
      return InvMod(res, n);
   else
      return res;
}
```

Comment: Actually i can't use any external library.Is this the only way to do that ?

Comment: @chotabheem Well, you could also invest a few months of development to write it yourself. But yes, C++ only supports relatively small integers, 128 bit at most currently, I think.

Comment: Could you at least tell us how you want to store those numbers anyway if you're not planning on using a library ?

Comment: @Lectem I seriously don't know how to store them .Can we do something like storing number as string and may do something to get the mod.something like that

Comment: That would be one more reason to use one of those libraries, manipulating extremely large number is really something you don't want to program yourself unless you're writing a library... In C and C++ at least.

Comment: I agree with Lectem - if you cannot use a library you essentially need to reinvent the wheel and implement long integer arithmetic library yourself.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution(maybe)

So,here goes explaination.If we want to calculate mod of very big numbers that cannot be stored as any data type than we have to take number as a **string**.Than we will do something like this

```
 int remainder(string &s,first)
 {
   int rem=0;
   for(int i=0;i<s.length();++i)
   rem=rem*10+(s[i]-'0');//Explaining this below
   return rem;
 }
```

Why does it work ?Take a paper and pen and start doing division of string with the number first(taking 100) for ease.

```
  For example, for 1234 % 100.
  1 mod 100 = 1
  12 mod 100 =(1 * 10 + 2) mod 100 =12
  123 mod 100 =(12 * 10 + 3) mod 100 =23
  1234 mod 100 =(23 * 10 + 4) mod 100 =34
```

**PS:This is my first answer.Sorry i wrote answer to my own question but i thought it would be good for future readers.**

Comment: Your solution does NOT use the divisor... the `first` argument in your remainder() function! So as displayed on this page your solution IS NOT A SOLUTION at all.